# печать Java в формате xml, json

Tags: java, json, xml, печать

как напечатать объект в java  в формате json  или xml?
переопределив toString?

Comment: Почитайте про сериализацию.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотеки Simple Json, GSON, Jackson имеют методы не только для парсинга json, но и для их создания на основе объекта. Если объект сложный, с множеством полей и не все из них нужно помещать в итоговую строку, то придётся прибегнуть к сериализации. На хабре хорошая статья на эту тему:
https://habr.com/ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/